# "MFC Application has stopped working"

Tags: mfc

I have an SDI in which there is a:

```
AfxGetMainWnd()->PostMessageW(WM_CLOSE);
```

in the `OnInitialUpdate()` in the `*View` class.

The application closes and a few seconds later a

> "MFC Application has stopped working"

window appears with the option to
(a) Check online for a solution and close the program
(b) Close the program
(c) Debug the program

Can someone please tell me what I can do to get rid of this problem?

Comment: Your favorite debugger will tell you more.

Comment: The debugger says: Unhandled exception at 0x2022201D in test.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation executing location 0x2022201D. I do not know what this means. Can you please help?

Comment: Your program probably uses an invalid pointer. Again: Just debug!

Comment: The debugger should show you where exactly the error occured. For debugging this kind of error you must learn how to use a debugger.

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the AfxGetMainWnd()->PostMessageW(WM_CLOSE).  It's retarded.

Basically, it's closing the windows application immediately.  It makes no sense to spin up an SDI MFC application that is going to do that.  You might as well write a console application.

And yes, you need to learn how to use the debugger.  I'm sure it is telling you exactly what is wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How would you close an SDI MFC application?

Comment: @user: You don't. The user does.

Comment: The user clicks on the close button or File - Exit and the program shuts down.

Comment: @user2859884 You could send WM_CLOSE as you do, but not in OnInitialUpdate at every application start -  that makes no sense.